# Image source not readable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to resize my images with Intervention Image package.

My application is working smoothly when uploading small size images. But when I try to upload a large size image, my application stops working on the deployment server!

Locally my code is working fine, but I'm getting this error on my deployment server:

> (1/1) NotReadableException,
>   Image source not readable

***Here is my code:***

```
$files= Input::file('image');
foreach($files as $file){
    $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
    $image_resize->save(public_path('images/gallery/small/' .$imageName));
}
```

How can I fix this? Please explain me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the values of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` on your server? If you can't access your `php.ini` directly, this code may help to determine it:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('post_max_size') . '<br>';
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
?>
```

This [comment](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/148#issuecomment-65815989) on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/148) makes me believe that your error can be thrown when you're trying to upload a file that's bigger than your server will accept.

You can tackle this by increasing the maximum sizes in your `php.ini` and additionally, since there will still be a maximum that you'll accept, checking the `max_file_size` on the client side: `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="123456">`.